# Why is this integral divergent?

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

I am making a mistake and I don't quite see where. Consider the following integral
$$
I\equiv\int_2^{\infty}\frac{e^{-x}-1}{x}\frac{\log\frac{1}{x}}{\log^2\frac{1}{x}+\frac{\pi^2}{4}}dx
$$
I have plotted the integrand and the function $\frac{1}{x^{1.1}}$. My mathematica tells me that up to $x=10000$ the integrand above is smaller than $\frac{1}{x^{1.1}}$. It is well-known that
$$
\int_2^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^{1.1}}dx
$$
is convergent. Therefore, I expect my integral to be convergent.

Nonetheless, when I proceed with integration by parts I encounter infinities. This is how. Noticing
$$
\int\frac{\log\frac{1}{x}}{x(\log^2\frac{1}{x}+\frac{\pi^2}{4})}dx=-\frac{1}{2}\log(\pi^2+4\log^2\frac{1}{x})
$$
I can write
$$
I=(e^{-x}-1)\big(-\frac{1}{2}\log(\pi^2+4\log^2\frac{1}{x})\big)\bigg|_2^{\infty}-\frac{1}{2}\int_2^{\infty}e^{-x}\log(\pi^2+4\log^2\frac{1}{x})
$$
and we encounter an infinity in the first term above. Where did I go wrong?
EDIT: picture of the plot in Mathematica. The blue line is the integrand and the orange one $1/x^{1.1}$[image]

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**. Your integral is divergent because, as $x \to \infty$,
$$
\frac{e^{-x}-1}{x}\frac{\log\frac{1}{x}}{\log^2\frac{1}{x}+\frac{\pi^2}{4}} \sim\frac{-1}{x}\frac{\log\frac{1}{x}}{\log^2\frac{1}{x}} \sim \frac{1}{x\log x}
$$ and the latter integrand gives a divergent integral over $[2,\infty)$. One may recall that, as $M \to \infty$,
$$
\int_2^M \frac{1}{x\log x}\:dx =\left[\frac{}{}\log\left(\log x \right) \right]_2^M =\log\left(\log M\right) -\log\left(\log 2 \right) \to \infty.
$$

Comment: I thought about that, but why is it the integrand then smaller than $1/x^{1.1}$ always?

Comment: @AnarchistBirdsWorshipFungus Do you have any picture of it?

Comment: Plot added in the question

Comment: @AnarchistBirdsWorshipFungus Thanks. How do you know which one is the blue curve?

Comment: I have checked it

Comment: @AnarchistBirdsWorshipFungus See my answer for an explanation of why the graph is unconvincing.

Answer (score 1):

When working with convergence questions, very often when logs are involved, graphing up to $x=100000$ is not good enough.  Convergence/divergence **only** cares about what happens as $x\to\infty$.

You are essentially comparing $\log x$ and $x^{0.1}$.  You *know* that asymptotically any positive power of $x$ is eventually larger than $\log x$.  But consider that $\log 100000 \approx 11.5$, while $100000^{0.1} \approx 3.2$.  This doesn't mean that what you know is wrong, it only means that $x = 100000$ is absolutely tiny compared to the scale that is relevant when comparing these two functions.  Try $x=10^{100}$ and we see that $\log x \approx 230$ while $x^{0.1} = 10^{10}$ is obviously so much larger.

The moral here is if you need to determine behaviour at infinity, graphing up to $x=100000$ (or even $x=10^{100}$) will never be completely conclusive.  You're only looking at only a microscopic sliver of the whole picture.